# How do I find the version of my Windows Feature Experience Pack?

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-core, registry, wmi

I see the "Experience" value in Settings:

[image: About Settings Experience Version]

I am familiar with `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\`. But I don't see anything there.

Assuming I identified the correct feature, DISM shows

```
DISM /Online /Get-CapabilityInfo /CapabilityName:Windows.Client.ShellComponents~~~~0.0.1.0

Capability Identity : Windows.Client.ShellComponents~~~~0.0.1.0
Name : Windows.Client.ShellComponents
State : Installed
Display Name : Windows Feature Experience Pack
Description : User Experience for Windows
Download Size : 5.36 MB
Install Size : 22.07 MB
```

How can I query the Experience value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's related to AppPackage "MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS"

```bsh
PS> Get-AppxPackage 'MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS'


Name              : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 120.2212.31.0
PackageFullName   : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.31.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy
InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
PublisherId       : cw5n1h2txyewy
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : True
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : System
Status            : Ok
```

Comment: Where did you get your information from? Is there someplace I can learn more?

Comment: First, I just tried to find that version in the registry (with Nirsoft's RegScanner; more easily to look for something). Then I found the Package Name already.

Other locations where you can find almost anything: In CIM/WIM Instances.
But that could be time consuming due to the bunch of available classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WMI call to get at least some of the data. (Architecture, Language, Name, ProgramID, Vendor and Version)

Query 'Win32_InstalledStoreProgram' and look for 'MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS'.

There may be multiple versions installed but a quick sort for highest version should report the same info as what is being shown in the Settings UI.

btw. This query needs to be run with admin rights.